# add elements of associative array with same key

Tags: php, associative-array

I have associative array like this

```
 $min_stats=
 array(2) 
{ 
[0]=> array(3) 
    { 
        ["minute"]=> object(MongoInt64)#13 (1) 
             { 
                ["value"]=> string(8) "10"
             } 
        ["add"]=> object(MongoInt64)#14 (1) 
            {
                 ["value"]=> string(1) "9"
            }
         ["tag"]=> object(MongoInt64)#15 (1) 
            {       
                ["value"]=> string(1) "4"
            }
     }
 [1]=> array(3) 
    { 
        ["minute"]=> object(MongoInt64)#13 (1) 
             { 
                ["value"]=> string(8) "11"
             } 
        ["add"]=> object(MongoInt64)#14 (1) 
            {
                 ["value"]=> string(1) "9"
            }
         ["tag"]=> object(MongoInt64)#15 (1) 
            {       
                ["value"]=> string(1) "5"
            }
    } 
} Array
```

Now I want to combine all the key-value pair in the array to get one array.
The resulting array should be

```
array(11) 
    { 
        ["minute"]=> int(21) 
        ["add"]=> int(18) 
        ["tag"]=> int(9) 
     } Array
```

so for what I have written is

```
foreach ($min_stats as $k=>$subArray) {
          foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
            $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
          }
        }
```

but its not giving me correct results, I don't know what I'm doing wrong?
The $value is coming as 2 means its just counting the elements in the subarray.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to use the outer key as id. And initialize the elements with 0 if they don't exist.

Comment: I don't understand, Can you give me a quick demo of what you are saying,

Comment: Please can you give me code, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$finalArr = array();
foreach($array as $k1 => $v1){
    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
        if(!isset($finalArr[$k2])){
            $finalArr[$k2] = 0;
        }
        $finalArr[$k2] += $v2['value'];
    }
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

Output:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [minute] => 21
>     [add] => 18
>     [tag] => 9
> )
> ```

---

Easy copy array for testing:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'minute' => array(
            'value' => '10'
        ),
        'add' => array(
            'value' => '9'
        ),
        'tag' => array(
            'value' => '4'
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'minute' => array(
            'value' => '11'
        ),
        'add' => array(
            'value' => '9'
        ),
        'tag' => array(
            'value' => '5'
        ),
    )
);
```